# Assistance to create using regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have been using a simple regex `when /^NICK/i` in Ruby however now I need to make the code a little more complex so I need to split it in to 2 regex.

I have these 2 strings:

```
NICK Sharon 1 1434981375 Female 178.167.196.67 server. 0 +iwx * sqfEQw== :Sharon
```

Here only the `NICK` at the start stays the same on each time.

and

```
:Dave NICK Dave2 1434981415
```

Here only the `:` before the first word, and `NICK` as the second word stays the same each time.

I need to make **2 regex** to match these, but they must not match each other either, is it possible?

Comment: So, you want two regexes, or one that does both jobs?

Comment: Do you mean you have an array (say, `a`) of several strings, each having `"NICK"` at the beginning of the string or after the first word (that is preceded by a colon), and want to divide them into like groups?  If so, you can do that with the simple regex `r = /\ANICK\s/`. The first group is `b = a.select { |s| s =~ r }`; the other, `a-b`.

Comment: [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) is a great resource to learn about and test regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
/^(?:\S+\s+)?NICK/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for second case:

```
/^:\w+ NICK/i
```

Example:

```
":Dave NICK Dave2 1434981415" =~ /^:\w+ NICK/i
# => 0

"NICK Sharon 1 1434981375 Female 178.167.196.67 server. 0 +iwx * sqfEQw== :Sharon" =~ /^:\w+ NICK/i
# => nil
```

For first string example, your existing regex should work fine.

Comment: this should work fine for the 2nd string, as for first condition OP has posted the regex in question itself?

Comment: You should add that to the answer. Just posting code without any explanation often attracts downvotes.